# Java 8: Function (Expression) which only returns a value and does not accept any argument

Tags: java

In .Net Frameworks, we have the `Func<out TResult>` which may or may not take any argument but returns something. To be specific, when using this we can do:

```
int funcTest (Func<int> arg){ return arg();}
-->
int i = funcTest(()=>{return 1;})
```

This is while the `Function` in Java always requires an input argument(`Function<T,R>`). This is while, there are scenarios where we need expressions similar to the .Net example I explained in the beginning of the question. Although these cases can be handled by passing a null, zero, true/false, or any other dummy value as argument to the expression, this would definitely not be a standard and wise solution for handling such situations.

I have searched the `java.util.function` library and I found that the majority of the expression types in that namespace require an input argument, so I decided to post this question to see if there's any expression provided in the java standard library similar to the `Func<Result>` in .Net.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The interface [`java.util.function.Supplier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) is what you are looking for: a function that takes no arguments and returns a value.

```
int funcTest(Supplier<Integer> arg) {
    return arg.get();
}

int i = funcTest(() -> 1);
```

There are also specialized suppliers to avoid [auto-(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), for example `IntSupplier`:

```
int funcTest(IntSupplier arg) {
    return arg.get();
}

int i = funcTest(() -> 1);
```

If you use this, the `int` doesn't have to be boxed and unboxed to and from `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, that is exactly what I was after. +1

Comment: So does `Callable`, but `Supplier` is a better choice unless you are submitting it as a task to an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a `Supplier<T>` ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)). You can find the default suppliers for primitives in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html):

```
Interface           Description
BooleanSupplier     Represents a supplier of boolean-valued results.
DoubleSupplier      Represents a supplier of double-valued results.
IntSupplier         Represents a supplier of int-valued results.
LongSupplier        Represents a supplier of long-valued results.
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the [`java.util.function.Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)

Another interface obeying that contract would be [`java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

Of notice here is that when you return primitives (such as `int`, `boolean` and so on), you will have to rely on the Primitive Specializations such as: [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html) or [`BooleanSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html)